# Yii2 : How to highlight selected action in index page?

Tags: php, html, yii2-basic-app

In index page i have employee table in that ,3 buttons such as Active, Inactive and All employee .how to always highlight clicked button.

I tried like this,

```
  <?=Html::a('All Employees', ['all'], ['class'=>'nav-pills nav-     stacked','style' => 'margin-left:555px;']) ?>

  <?=Html::a('Active Employees', ['index'], ['class'=>'nav nav-pills' ]) ?>

  <?=Html::a('InActive Employees', ['inactive'], ['class'=>'nav nav-pills']) ?>
```

Please anyone help me....Thanks

Comment: Maybe just use CSS to highlight active link?

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery for Bootstrap styles:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```